Movin' On Up (Theme to The Jeffersons) 2 Lyrics line question
In the Jeffersons theme song there are two lines I don't understand:

Fish don't fry in the kitchen

Does this mean they are now wealthy enough to have fish catered? But they still cook in the kitchen?

Beans don't burn on the grill.

Same question.

Song lyrics could mean anything, or nothing, or just sound good. Related: fish to fry means you have matters to deal with. I don't know about the beans.

Fish and beans both are “economical” (cheap) foods.

I am minutes old new to this site and don’t really know how it works. But I can’t believe I found this thread or whatever the terminology would be here. My partner and I just had the most heated discussion about the lyrics of “fish don’t fry in the kitchen, beans don’t burn on the grill”. I go to google and there’s a whole group of people from the past couple of days discussing this? Just thought that was amazing and wild and hilarious. Anyway, take care comrades lmao. Edited to add: Please bear with me trying to learn how this site works. I found it drunkenly, but now I’m starting to apprecia

Fish don't fry in the kitchen conveys that things do not always happen where or in the way you expect them to.
This particular song speaks about moving up on the social ladder, becoming rich from poor. You expect the poor to live in poor areas, but the song shows that if you have opportunity and you persistently make the effort, this can change. Fish don't fry in the kitchen is a metaphorical images of the poor having access to success against all odds, so that you will find them, not in the poverty you would expect, but in a life of luxury because they moved up "to the East Side".
Having said that, we must keep in mind that it is a song after all, and although all the connotations I have mentioned are present, you cannot claim with the authority of a dictionary that this is the whole meaning of these idioms. Songs are very flexible, subjective and can be interpreted in many ways.
EDIT: I thank the downvoters for prompting me to check the information of the site which was accused of AI generated information, and to my shock, I could not find any support for that post. So I edited my post to delete it. It's a good lesson, next time I will check, as I never trust AI and would hate to propagate its gibberish.

I think this is a very good answer. It makes total sense. I will wait some more. I cannot upvote, as I am a newbie.

Wow, both those sources sound like utter nonsense.

The site re fish is fine.

In point of fact, I think it's your first line, not either of the dubious AI interpretations, that is closest to correct. One would expect baked beans to burn if prepared on a grill with high temperatures and uneven heating, too.

@Obie2.0 — Yes, 100% hallucination on “Joe C. Turner.” And there is zero evidence on the entire internets (including academic databases) that the phrase “Fish don’t fry in the kitchen” existed anywhere prior to the theme song. Wish I could downvote this twice for its spread of AI-generated misinformation/nonsense.

Please see this meta question asking why you've just migrated a question of ours. I'll remove this comment here once you've answered that meta question in its answer box. Thank you.

I don't really get how or why this phrase would be linked to this meaning. It sounds like the interpretation is "fish [aren't always] fried in the kitchen, [they can be found frying somewhere else]", rather than "fish don't fry in the kitchen [at all]". But where else do fish fry, if not in the kitchen? You don't randomly find fish frying in places where you do not expect them, I don't see why this phrase would connote something found in an unexpected place. It strikes me as a very strange metaphor to liken the Jeffersons to a fish being fried outside of a kitchen.

I don't have a separate reference for this, but I always understood it as Tinfoil Hat's comment mentions: fish and beans are inexpensive fare in many places.   If you eat them constantly, you get annoyed with them.
If you're forced to cook a lot of fish indoors often, the cooking grease gets everywhere and is a pain to clean.   One night of fish can be interesting, but multiple days of fish and you get very tired of the odor.
Fish frying in the kitchen (often) is annoying because of the smell and grease.
Beans burning on the grill is a problem that happens when you're constantly  cooking beans (because they burn easily if not constantly attended).
The song is celebrating that these are two annoyances that they expect to leave behind by having more money.

From https://www.tuscaloosanews.com/story/opinion/columns/2017/07/15/outdoors-nothing-can-destroy-fish-fry/20255464007/ "Fish fries are properly done outside so that a greasy film and fishy smell do not coat the indoors".

In their move to the Upper East Side, the Jeffersons leave behind—metaphorically, if not literally—soul food, or what Wikipedia describes as the “ethnic cuisine of African Americans.” Born of subsistence hunting, fishing, and farming by slaves in the antebellum Deep South, the economical cuisine was “seen as low-class food.” (Wikipedia—Soul food)
For a sociological take on the role of food and dining in African American culture, you can read  Every Nation Has Its Dish: Black Bodies and Black Food in Twentieth-Century America, wherein author Jennifer Jensen Wallach analyzes “the various attempts of African Americans who . . . used food practices [to experiment] with different ideas about who they were and who they wished to become.” But the “tl;dr” can be found in those two lines of the theme song: Fish don’t fry in the kitchen; Beans don’t burn on the grill.
So, no more fried fish and beans for the Jeffersons — at least not emanating from their deluxe kitchen. They eat like upper-middle-class folks now. In this scene from The Jeffersons, George explains the concept of “brunch” to a perplexed Weezy:

. . . that’s how rich folks get more time to enjoy their money—because
they make one meal do the work of two. I call that smart.

Weezy replies:

When we had to do it in Harlem, it was called poverty.

The lyrics extend the food metaphor by trading the, uh, aromatic fish and beans for “a piece of the pie”—the sweet smell of success, maybe.

Wow, this simple question just turned into a twilight zone episode. So now we are dealing with AI bs? Can you do anything on the interweb thatis not corrupted?

@birdpoolcleaner — What do you mean?

@ Tinfoil Hat (btw it's always good to have a hat). Anyways you brought up the possibility that you cannot trust any sources on the internet because of AI, no?
